# Highchart Category Label not showing in angular 7

Tags: angular, highcharts

Currently the category label in pie chart of Highchart not showing.
When I inspect to tspan that is created for that value it is having x="5" and y="16".
It is only happening when we tspan has large value or value with specific currency symbol that is large.
I have tried all the things on internet i.e. overlapp,crop,width,etc, but nothing worked for me.
When I try to change the value of y from 16 to 15-30, the value seems to be visible, actually the value is been hidden behind some overlapping area.

Highchart version - 6.2.0

Comment: what have you tried so far..?Please post your code sample

Comment: 1) crop:"false" 2)  format:'{point.y}' (this shows the value but not with currency), also checked many other things from highchart officials like setting overlap with different values but nothing worked

Comment: Could you reproduce the issue in the online editor so I can take a look at your config? You can start from this template: https://stackblitz.com/edit/highcharts-angular-basic-line

Answer (score 0):

I have got the fix by adding

```
textOutline:'false'
```

in plotoptions->datalabels->style 
and, 
added a css for tspan with `text-decoration` & `text-shadow` to 'none' (if not work then add !important with 'none')